# Angular2. Exception: No Directive annotation found on Alert

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-template, angular2-directives, ng2-bootstrap

I am getting the following exception in my browser logs:

> No Directive annotation found on Alert

Stacktrace:

```
Error: No Directive annotation found on Alert
at new BaseException (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/facade/exceptions.js?:15:23)
at DirectiveResolver.resolve (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/linker/directive_resolver.js?:41:15)
at RuntimeMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/runtime_metadata.js?:41:51)
at eval (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/runtime_metadata.js?:98:62)
at Array.map (native)
at Array.map (webpack:///./~/es6-shim/es6-shim.js?:1113:14)
at RuntimeMetadataResolver.getViewDirectivesMetadata (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/runtime_metadata.js?:98:27)
at TemplateCompiler._compileNestedComponentRuntime (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_compiler.js?:151:65)
at eval (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_compiler.js?:136:87)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Array.forEach (webpack:///./~/es6-shim/es6-shim.js?:1107:14)
at eval (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_compiler.js?:136:43)
at Zone.run (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:1216:24)
at Zone.eval [as run] (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.js?:344:42)
at zoneBoundFn (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:1193:26)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:441:17)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:453:18)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:424:12)
at eval (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:96:10)
at microtask (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.js?:384:29)
at Zone.run (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:1216:24)
at Zone.eval [as run] (webpack:///./~/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.js?:344:42)
at zoneBoundFn (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:1193:26)
at MutationObserver.lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush (webpack:///./~/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js?:235:10)
```

How to fix it?

---

Core libraries:

- Angular 2
- [Angular 2 bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap)

Build system:

- [Webpack](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

---

### Here is my source code:

**Angular 2 bootstrap ['alert.component.ts'](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/master/components/alert/alert.component.ts)**

> This part of code belongs to **ng2-bootstrap** framework.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'alert',
  directives: [NgIf, NgClass],
  template: ALERT_TEMPLATE
})
export class Alert {
  ......
}
```

**My project App component**

```
.... Other imports ....
import {Alert} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [],
    directives: [Alert],    // <----- THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    pipes: [],
    styles: [require('./app.component.scss')],
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Index'}
])
export class App extends Type {
    title: string = 'Hello';

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

}
```

**Bootstrap script**

> Full source code of bootstrap script is [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/main.ts)

```
export function main() {
    return browser.bootstrap(App)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

**My tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "src/custom-typings.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useCache": true,
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "cacheDirectory": "node_modules/.awesome-typescript-loader-cache"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

**Webpack loaders:**

```
loaders: [
    // Support for .ts files.
    {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]},   

 // Support for *.json files.
    {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},

    // Support for CSS as raw text
    {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader'},

    // Support for SASS as raw text
    {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']},

    // Support for .html as raw text
    {test: /\.html$/, loaders: ['raw-loader']}
]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.6",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^0.16.0-rc.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.8",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.21",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "ng2lint": "0.0.10",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "parse5": "^1.3.2",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "properties-parser": "^0.3.1",
    "protractor": "^3.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^0.5.5",
    "tslint": "^3.5.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.8",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "registry:npm/es6-promise#3.0.0+20160211003958",
    "moment": "registry:npm/moment#2.10.5+20160211003958",
    "source-map": "registry:npm/source-map#0.4.0+20160211003958"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160127022504",
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160215162030",
    "hammerjs": "registry:dt/hammerjs#2.0.4+20160103211821",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160308082659",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160311162451",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20150825165336",
    "uglify-js": "registry:dt/uglify-js#2.6.1+20160106153543",
    "webpack": "registry:dt/webpack#1.12.9+20160125043835"
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `template: ALERT_TEMPLATE`?

Comment: Oh okay it belongs to `ng2-bootstrap`, I thought it belongs to your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, make sure both angular2 versions match in your `app -> package.json` and in `ng2-bootstrap -> package.json`

You npm install the packages. If the version of angular2 does not match the version of a dependency (who also has a dependency on angular2) it causes npm to put that in a sub-folder of the dependency (which is correct).

So the structure becomes something like:

```
|->node_modules
|      |-> angular2@beta8
|      |->ng2-bootstrap
|      |        |->node_modules 
|      |        |        |->angular2@beta7
```

The idea here is that a package can have a dependency on a different version (one of the benefits of npm packages). But with angular2 it causes some weird duplication error that is not shown to the developer.

If you are suffering from this problem currently the easiest fix is to go into the ng2-bootstrap sub-folder and rename the node_modules folder to _node_modules until the dependencies within the ng2-bootstrap package.json are changed to peer dependencies.

You can also open an issue in [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) and they will help you out.

*credit @ekarlso from [this](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/issues/38) issue.*

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem. Recently I wasted a day to find solution ...

Comment: I just want to note that if you upgrade to Angular2 beta 16 and ng2-bootstrap 1.0.14, dependencies should be solved.